# Facebook Intent.ACTION_SEND returns always 0 as resultCode

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to share a photo on Facebook using my application and starting the Intent.ACTION_SEND. My code is the following:

```
File file = new File(imagePath);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType(MimeTypeUtils.getMimeType(imagePath));
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
baseFragment.startActivityForResult(sharingIntent, Values.REQUEST_CODE_FACEBOOK_SHARE);
```

I'm doing the share without problems however, I always get a 0 (zero) as result even if I cancel the operation or perform it successfully. I have to call the startActivityForResult because I need to receive a Result to keep a record about my shares. My code to handle the result code is the following:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   case Values.REQUEST_CODE_FACEBOOK_SHARE:
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        //Save a new record
     }
     else {
        //Do nothing
     }
   break;
}
```

The application never enters the if clause because the result code is always 0. I have no idea what's happening. I think that the implemented mechanism is the expected. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have to call the startActivityForResult because I need to receive a Result to keep a record about my shares

`ACTION_SEND` is not designed to return a result, as noted in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) ("Output: nothing"). Few, if any, apps will return a result, and those that do technically shouldn't.

Comment: So @CommonsWare, is impossible to know the result of the operation?

Comment: @TiagoPereira: Correct.

Comment: I tried the same code with 3 different applications (dropbox, google+ and twitter) and all of them returned a correct resultCode (0 if I cancel the operation and 1 if i perform it). What can I conclude from this?

Comment: @TiagoPereira: You can conclude that the developers of Dropbox, Google+, and Twitter are remarkably generous, for the current versions of those apps, for the particular flows in those apps that you performed. There is no requirement for `ACTION_SEND`-handling activities to call `setResult()` to give you a result code, and there is no requirement that the value you get back as that result would necessarily line up with whatever you might be thinking indicates "cancel" versus "perform".

Comment: thank you very much. Do you know if exists any alternative to perform the same action as ACTION_SEND and get feedback about the result?

Comment: @TiagoPereira: Depending on what you are trying to share and where you are trying to share it to, there may be a dedicated API that you can use. For example, Facebook has an SDK, IIRC.

Comment: @TiagoPereira, I'm facing same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: @hara, I was unable to solve the problems, so I had to change the behaviour of my app. Idk if this is already possible with new Android releases once I'm working on iOS those days.